# Need help on SQL query (self join)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
MAIN ID CONTENT SUB ID

ABCD    ONE     888

ABCD    TWO     888
```

which i would like the query result to be like this

```
MAIN ID SUB ID  CONTENT1  CONTENT2

ABCD    888      ONE         TWO
```

Comment: More like a pivot query.

Comment: You can do it by PIVOT like here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542982/pivot-function-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select
  *
from (
  select
    [main id],
    [sub id],
    [content],
    'content' + cast(
        row_number() over (partition by [main id],[sub id] order by content)
     as varchar(5)) as contentIX
  from
    table1
) T
pivot (max(Content) for contentIX in (content1,content2)) as content
```

The subquery first generates a field name for each result to pivot, `content1`, `content2`, etc. that looks like this:

```
| MAIN ID | SUB ID | CONTENT | CONTENTIX |
|---------|--------|---------|-----------|
|    ABCD |    888 |     ONE | content1  |
|    ABCD |    888 |     TWO | content2  |
```

Then the outer query performs a pivot over the `CONTENTIX` column  to get the final result:

```
| MAIN ID | SUB ID | CONTENT1 | CONTENT2 |
|---------|--------|----------|----------|
|    ABCD |    888 |      ONE |      TWO |
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/095bb/11

Comment: solve my problem, thanks!